Dart/Flutter remove element from nested map by searching key
I am trying to remove element from nested my by searching the key but I am getting error
Concurrent modification during iteration: Instance of 'IdentityMap<String, String>'.
void main() {
  Map<String, dynamic> nestedMap = {
    'key1': 'value1',
    'key2': {
      'nestedKey1': 'nestedValue1',
      'nestedKey2': 'nestedValue2',
    },
    'key3': {
      'nestedKey3': {
        'nestedKey4': 'nestedValue3',
      },
    },
  };

  String keyToRemove = 'nestedKey2';

  // Traverse the nested map and remove the specific key
  removeKeyFromNestedMap(nestedMap, keyToRemove);

  // Print the updated nested map
  print(nestedMap);
}

void removeKeyFromNestedMap(Map<String, dynamic> map, String keyToRemove) {
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value is Map) {
      removeKeyFromNestedMap(value, keyToRemove);
    } else if (key == keyToRemove) {
      map.remove(key);
    }
  });
}


The error you are getting is due the map is modified and itrated at the same time. you are looping through the map and the same time you are removing item from it. to counter this issue there are two solutions either

copy the map in a second map and itertate that map and remove item from the original map. like this:


void removeKeyFromNestedMap(Map map, String keyToRemove) {
  // Create a new map to store the filtered elements
  final filteredMap = Map<String, dynamic>.from(map);

  filteredMap.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value is Map) {
      removeKeyFromNestedMap(value, keyToRemove);
    } else if (key == keyToRemove) {
      map.remove(key);
    }
  });
}


or save the key with yourself and remove item from the map when the itretation is completed like this:

void removeKeyFromNestedMap(Map map, String keyToRemove) {
  String keyc = "";
  map.forEach((key, value) {
    if (value is Map) {
      removeKeyFromNestedMap(value, keyToRemove);
    } else {
      if (key == keyToRemove) {
        keyc = key;
      }
    }
  });
  if (keyc.isNotEmpty) {
    map.remove(keyc);
  }
}


are parameters pass by reference? If I am deleting element from Map parameter i.e. Map<String, dynamic> map , its also deleting from argument i.e. nestedMap

yes it is passed by reference you can check it in dartpad

You can't change a map while iterating it. Having said that, it's actually okay to try to remove the key from the map even if you don't know if it's in it, so you don't even need to check if the key is in it. So you could do this:
void removeKeyFromNestedMap(Map map, String keyToRemove) {
  map.remove(keyToRemove);
  for (var value in map.values) {
    if (value is Map) {
      removeKeyFromNestedMap(value, keyToRemove);
    }
  }
}


are parameters pass by reference? If I am deleting element from Map parameter i.e. Map<String, dynamic> map , its also deleting from argument i.e. nestedMap

This function should work as expected, but I think "pass by reference" is the incorrect term, because I think this is actually considered "pass by value" because if you would do inside the function something like map = {}; it wouldn't change the original nestedMap. But I would say, just try it out with an example and you'll see if it works to your liking

I'd also suggest reading this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference-or-pass-by-value . Even though it is about Java it gives a good explanation of what it means to be pass by reference

You are right, but this is very strange when I am trying to change complete object its not working. But when I am trying to change only value of key it works. Don't know what to say if its call by reference or value.
